# Ember Computed Sort ascending

Tags: javascript, sorting, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am trying to sort by date the repos in GitHub using their JSON API.

I am using Ember 1.13.7

I have reproduced my case in [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zalunazedo/edit?html,js,output), the problem is that i can not even see the console error to understand the problem

This is the code applied ( it is commented in the [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zalunazedo/edit?html,js,output) )

In my controller

```
sortProperties: ['created_at:asc'],
sortedRepos: Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortProperties')
```

in My Template

```
{{#each model.repos in sortedRepos}}
   <li>{{name}}</li>
   <li>{{format-date "LL" created_at}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

What' s the error here? how can i sort this model by date ( the latest )?

P.s I am using an helper template {{format-date}} with moment js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is working [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qezocakepi/1/edit?html,js,output)

you were sorting wrong property it should be `model.repos` not `model` and in jsbin you were creating sorted computed property in `ApplicationController` not `IndexController`

by the way you are using old iteration style/syntax once you upgrade your ember to `2.x.x` you should be using

```
{{#each sortedRepos as |repo|}}
   <li>{{repo.name}}</li>
   <li>{{format-date "LL" repo.created_at}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: great, thanks, i will be update to 2.0 very soon, one more question if you can , how can i apply a limit of repos num for example {limit: 5}?

Comment: in your model hook you can slice the array and return on 5 items, or you can create another computed prooperty which will take only 5 reops